# Converting hours to milliseconds

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to convert some minutes and hours to milliseconds but the code below does not work.

I have tried lower numbers and it seamed to kind of work, is there a number limit in ahk?

ConvertedTimeInMilliSeconds := %Hours% * 3600000 + %Minutes% * 60000

I was expecting Hours to be 7200000 if the input would be two but instead its blank.

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable names in an [expression](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Expressions) are not enclosed in percent signs:

```
Hours = 15
Minutes = 48

ConvertedTimeInMilliSeconds := (Hours * 3600000) + (Minutes * 60000)
MsgBox, % ConvertedTimeInMilliSeconds
```

or use a [function](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm):

```
MsgBox, % ConvertTimeInMilliSeconds(15, 48)

ConvertTimeInMilliSeconds(Hours, Minutes){
TimeInMilliSeconds := (Hours * 3600000) + (Minutes * 60000)
return TimeInMilliSeconds
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common misunderstanding at the beginning.

I'll make this example, this are valid syntaxes:

```
Command, OutputVar, %InputVar%
Function(OutputVar, InputVar)
OutputVar := Function(InputVar)

OutputVar = %InputVar% Literal text
OutputVar := InputVar . " Literal text"
```

So in your code above, remove the % because you used an `:=` assignment. Assigning through `=` can be always worked around into `:=` and is probably the most recommended.